# Modifying builtin LUIS "datetimeV2' intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Wondering if there is a way to extend the DateTime built-in feature of LUIS.
While it handles "before" well, it doesn't seem to handle off versions like
"preceding" or "in advance of"  but I can't seem to get into the built-in DateTime to train/extend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LUIS recognizer for DateTime is open sourced at https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text. You can create an issue there for asking for this enhancement.